# How to check via callbacks if alpha is decreasing? + How to load all cores during training?

Tags: callback, gensim, multicore, word-embedding, doc2vec

I'm training doc2vec, and using callbacks trying to see if alpha is decreasing over training time using this code:

```
class EpochSaver(CallbackAny2Vec):
'''Callback to save model after each epoch.'''

    def __init__(self, path_prefix):
        self.path_prefix = path_prefix
        self.epoch = 0

        os.makedirs(self.path_prefix, exist_ok=True)

    def on_epoch_end(self, model):
        savepath = get_tmpfile(
            '{}_epoch{}.model'.format(self.path_prefix, self.epoch)
        )
        model.save(savepath)
        print(
            "Model alpha: {}".format(model.alpha), 
            "Model min_alpha: {}".format(model.min_alpha),
            "Epoch saved: {}".format(self.epoch + 1),
            "Start next epoch"
        )
        self.epoch += 1


def train():

    workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()*4
    model = Doc2Vec(
        DocIter(),
        vec_size=600, alpha=0.03, min_alpha=0.00025, epochs=20,
        min_count=10, dm=1, hs=1, negative=0, workers=workers,
        callbacks=[EpochSaver("./checkpoints")]
    )
    print(
        "HS", model.hs, "Negative", model.negative, "Epochs", 
         model.epochs, "Workers: ", model.workers, "Model alpha: 
         {}".format(model.alpha)
    )
```

And while training I see that alpha is not changing over time. On each callback I see alpha = 0.03.
Is it possible to check if alpha is decreasing? Or it really not decreasing at all during training?

One more question: 
How can I benefit from all my cores while training doc2vec?

[image: Loading of cores]

As we can see, each core is not loaded more than +-30%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `model.alpha` property only holds the initially-configured starting-`alpha` – it's not updated to the effective learning-rate through training.

So, even if the value is being decreased properly (and I expect that it is), you wouldn't see it in the logging you've added.

Separate observations about your code:

- in gensim versions at least through 3.5.0, maximum training throughput is most often reached with some value for `workers` between 3 and the number of cores – but usually not the full number of cores (if it's higher than 12) or larger. So `workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()*4` is likely going to much slower than what you could achieve with a lower number.
- if your corpus is large enough to support 600-dimensional vectors, and discarding words with fewer than `min_count=10` examples, negative sampling may work faster *and* get better results than the `hs` mode. (The pattern in published work seems to be to prefer negative-sampling with larger corpuses.)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your great answer! May I ask you one more? While training on my machine with 48 CPUs, train phase loads all cores on nearly 4-15%, how can I receive more benefits from my multicore machine? (Screenshot added to current question)

Comment: And one more, I have read at the article (which one I'll try to find, but I don't remember right now exactly), that if you have vector size more than 100 - hierarchical softmax will work better with them. And if less - you can use NS. What do you think about it?

Comment: Unfortunately bottlenecks in Python ("Global Interpreter Lock") and gensim's corpus iteration & thread-distribution code mean full saturation of 48 cores isn't possible. The usual max throughput occurs with 3-12 workers (rather than all cores). Things that can help a little with utilization are ensuring your corpus has already been tokenized (no extra processing done inside your `DocIter()`) and, if possible, completely in memory (no extra DB/IO). Also, sometimes larger `window` or `negative`-sampling or `vector_size` values improve utilization (but may not be optimal for your other goals).

Comment: That advice for choosing `hs`-vs-`negative` doesn't make any sense to me. Neither of those modes get relatively better or worse with `vector_size`. `hs` does get progressively slower as a function of the count of unique words (vocabulary size, not vector size). Published work with larger corpuses and larger vocabularies tends to use negative-sampling, as far as I can tell.